# DynDNS Not Accessible Outside of Local Network

Tags: dyndns

I have an account with DynDNS and it forwards my IP address to james.dontexist.net
I have a 'free' account with DynDNS and cannot find whether this is the reason that the URL is ineffective outside of my local network.

The other possibility in my mind is a complex one. I have a main Virgin SuperHub which is connected to the cable and works as a wireless router as well as the modem. Connected to that is a Belkin router which is more powerful. This Belkin router is the router that is handling the port forwarding. Could this be the reason that it is not working properly?

The reason that I am not using the Virgin SuperHub for the portforwading is because it does not support DynDNS.

Any help with this would be amazing. I am extremely inexperienced with matters to do with servers and appreciate any help.

Comment: You haven't actually explained your problem.

Comment: @joeqwerty Actually he did. It's just not on topic here.

Comment: No. He's made a statement that alludes to a problem but he hasn't explicitly asked a question or specifically stated the problem. - "the URL is ineffective outside of my local network" doesn't describe the problem in enough detail or context to provide an answer.

Comment: @joeqwerty I understood it well enough to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I understand and I'm not trying to be argumentative. I'm simply saying that personally, I expect the questions here to be presented in a professional and detailed manner with the problem and question specifically stated, which this question is decidedly not. This site is afterall focused toward professional systems administration, not to guessing, surmising  or assuming what the OP is getting at.

Comment: @joeqwerty That's why I voted to migrate it to [su]. It's perfectly on topic, understandable and answerable there.

Comment: I sincerely apologise for posting this question somewhere that it does not belong. I should have taken more time to read and find out where to ask this question.

Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
james.dontexist.net has address 192.168.2.2
```

You've set up your dynamic DNS entry to point to a private RFC 1918 address. These addresses are not routable on the public Internet, so nobody outside your LAN would ever be able to reach you.

To resolve the issue, use your public Internet address (provided by your ISP) instead. And strongly consider using a [dynamic DNS update client](http://dyn.com/support/clients/) on one of your computers, to keep it up to date automatically, if your ISP ever changes it.